# Unable to alter new item entry form in SharePoint 2019 modern experience

Tags: sharepoint-server, modern-experience, 2019

I'm not able to change the new item form for a list in SharePoint 2019, which is running with modern pages.

I've seen where designers/developers/admin click on the "`+ New`", have the "`New item`" pop-out appear from the right portion of the screen and are able to alter the fields they'd like to have appear at "`New item`" entry.

I do not see options to alter the "New item" pop out panel, even when logged in with increased permission (i.e.:Farm Admin, Site Collection admin, or Site admin).

The image below has been taken from a site where I'm logged in as site collection administrator:

[image]

I'm running SharePoint 2019 On-premises, Configuration database version: 16.0.10339.12102

If I've omitted any information you might find useful please ask.

Thanks for you help.

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is available on SharePoint Online, but not available in SharePoint server 2019:

[image]

More information for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration

Comment: Thanks, Julie.  Are creating classic SharePoint forms (i.e. with SP Designer) the recommended way  to customize/create New Item, Edit Item, Display Item  forms for Lists and Document Libraries with SP 2019 on prem?